# How do I copy a large file in chunks from a source file to a destination file using python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, file, copy, large-files

The file can be say 20GB. The traditional approach of importing,reading a file and then writing to another file is not feasible.

Comment: anything wrong with standard library module `shutil` ? https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copy

Comment: Well I am new to python and was trying out copying smaller files which got me thinking if I can do the same with larger files without using shutil.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`shutil`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html) module has a function designed for this purpose:

```
import shutil
shutil.copy(src, dst)
```

Comment: Your answer is correct. shutil.copy is the best way to deal with files with large size. As per http://www.pythoncentral.io/how-to-copy-a-file-in-python-with-shutil/, the metrics shows that shutil is faster for larger files. +1 vote.

Comment: Well I am new to python and was trying out copying smaller files which got me thinking if I can do the same with larger files without using shutil.

Comment: Why bother? shutil is meant for this type of thing.

Comment: What about file-like objects? An uploaded file, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For file-like objects (buffers, request bodies, etc.) you can use [shutil.copyfileobj](https://docs.python.org/3/library/shutil.html#shutil.copyfileobj)

```
with open('path/to/dest.file', 'wb') as dst:
    shutil.copyfileobj(source_file_like_object, dst)
```